# How to pass multiple parameter using json in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i want to pass Multiple parameter using json to controller. I have four fields in my View FromDate, ToDate, CustomerName, Count. if i select the FromDate. ToDate, CustomerName and click the ok button it have calculate and display the value in Count Textbox as per value selected in FromDate, ToDate ,CustomerName.

**My Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewExistingCustomer( CustomerViewModel cvm)
{
    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName");
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetCustomers()
{
    return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(Guid customerID, DateTime   fromdate, DateTime Todate)
{
    var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == customerID && sc.CreatedDate == fromdate && sc.CreatedDate == Todate select     sc.SalesOrderID).Count();
    return Json(salescount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here i calculate the SalesOrderCount from SalesOrderTable depend upon getting values of FromDate ToDate CustomerName from View and then i display the value in Count Textbox.
But it is not working. I donno where i did mistake . Please any one cross check my code again , it showing error

[image: Error]

**My View**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("FromDate", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID","Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.count)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.count, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.count)
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery**

```
function ok() {
    var customerID = $("#CustomerID").val();
    var fromdate = $("#FromDate").val();
    var Todate = $("ToDate").val();
    var ordercount = { "CustomerID": customerID, "FromDate": fromdate, "ToDate": Todate };
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")', {
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(ordercount),
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#count").val(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Advance Thanks

Comment: `'@Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")',` needs to be `url: @Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")',` (and the `{` before it

Comment: no stephen its not working

Comment: What is not working? It needs to be `$.ajax({ url: @Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")', type: "GET", ...}); and it will hit your method assuming that method is in `ReportController`

Comment: wait i will show my updated code

Comment: $.ajax({ url:' @Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")',
type: "GET",contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",async: false, data: JSON.stringify(ordercount),error: function (ex) {alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex); },beforeSend: function () { },
success: function (data) {$("#count").val(data);}     });

Comment: And that will work fine (assuming your script is not in an external file). What error are you now getting?

Comment: And why would you put the value of `count` in a textbox? (surely you do not want the value to be edited)

Comment: yes i dont want to edit that field

Comment: it showing same url error

Comment: Then add a `<div id="count"></div>` in the view and delete the associated `TextBoxFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` methods.

Comment: Then enter `/Report/GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer` in the address bar. Is the method being hit? And are you using areas? Also add `var url = @Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")';` at the beginning of the script and check what the output is.

Comment: stephen i  kept one alert message after var ordercount = { "CustomerID": customerID, "FromDate": fromdate, "ToDate": Todate }; and run my app it shows alert message then it show that error page sure the error is url but i tried many ways it showing same issue

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the data - its the url you need to test - see my last comment.

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'customerID' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(System.Guid, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'Sample_Customer.Controllers.ReportController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters i got this error when i hit directly using /Report/GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer

Comment: Dont worry about that error (you just not passing any parameters) - its was just to test that the method was being hit which it is. Now you need to test that `var url = @Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")';` is also producing that same url that your typed in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simplified way of doing it.

```
function ok() {
    var customerID = $("#CustomerID").val();
    var fromdate = $("#FromDate").val();
    var Todate = $("ToDate").val();
    var ordercount = { "CustomerID": customerID, "FromDate": fromdate, "ToDate": Todate };
/*$.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")', {
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(ordercount),
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#count").val(data);
        }
    });*/

    $.get('/Report/GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer', ordercount, function(response)
    {
        $('#count').val(respose);
    });
}
```

Comment: no kosala it showing the same page error but your code is correct but i donno why is not working

Comment: I think I know why. Use `string CustomerID` instead of `Guid customerID`.

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'customerID' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(System.Guid, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'Sample_Customer.Controllers.ReportController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters i got this error when i hit directly using /Report/GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer –

Comment: Have you converted the Guid type parameter to string type?

Comment: yes but i got error in this line  especially near to   sc.CustomerID == customerID                                                        public JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(Guid customerID, DateTime   fromdate, DateTime Todate)
{
    var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == customerID && sc.CreatedDate == fromdate && sc.CreatedDate == Todate select     sc.SalesOrderID).Count();
    return Json(salescount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == customerID && sc.CreatedDate == fromdate && sc.CreatedDate == Todate select     sc.SalesOrderID).Count();` and check if you are getting values for your parameters. If it does, rest of the errors are C# errors, which you should be able to sort out by yourself.